Deinterleave 24 bit audio buffer for ASIO output
I'm using an ASIO component (in Delphi 7) which supports only 16-bit and 32-bit output when it deinterleaves the left/right channels into 2 separate ASIO buffers. Some ASIO drivers only support 24-bit output so I want to add a deinterleaving function for this bit depth, but the bitwise logic required is beyond me.  Below are the DeInterleave32 and DeInterleave16 functions.  Can someone please help create a DeInterleave24 function.
type
  PASIOBufferInfo = ^TASIOBufferInfo;
  TASIOBufferInfo = packed record
    isInput    : TASIOBool;               // on input:  ASIOTrue: input, else output
    channelNum : longint;                 // on input:  channel index
    buffers    : array[0..1] of pointer;  // on output: double buffer addresses
  end;

  TBufferInfoArray = array[0..15] of TASIOBufferInfo;

  PBufferInfoArray = ^TBufferInfoArray;
  TBuffer32 = array[0..0] of LongWord;
  PBuffer32 = ^TBuffer32;

  TBuffer16 = array[0..0] of SmallInt;
  PBuffer16 = ^TBuffer16;

procedure Deinterleave32(InputBuffer : PBuffer32; OutputBuffer : PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex : LongWord);
var
  i, j : LongWord;
  Dest : array[0..1] of PBuffer32;
begin
  for i := 0 to 1 do // always 2 channels
    Dest[i] := OutputBuffer[i].buffers[BufferIndex];
  i := 0;
  while i < Samples do
  begin
    j := i shl 1;
    Dest[0][i] := InputBuffer[j];
    Dest[1][i] := InputBuffer[j+1];
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;

procedure Deinterleave16(InputBuffer : PBuffer16; OutputBuffer : PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex : LongWord);
var
  i, j : LongWord;
  Dest : array[0..1] of PBuffer16;
begin
  for i := 0 to 1 do // always 2 channels
    Dest[i] := OutputBuffer[i].buffers[BufferIndex];
  for i := 0 to Samples - 1 do
    for j := 0 to 1 do
      Dest[j][i] := InputBuffer[i*2 + j];
end;

Most appreciated if you can help.

I'm interested in helping you out, but I need more info about the layout of PBufferInfoArray, as well as the meaning (range) of BufferIndex.

Are TBuffer16 & TBuffer32 used for anything else, or can I jump in and restructure them? (For the sake of both readability and performance.)

It would be nice to know, how 24-bit data are stored. 3 bytes per element? 4 bytes?

@MBo It stores 3 bytes per element. 8 bits per byte, right? 24 / 8 = 3. I've completed this task and will post it in a few minutes.

I had very little information to go on. Some types were missing, as well as any information about the layout of the data. I therefore took myself a few liberties.

I rewrote both of your old procedures from scratch, this time using pointers instead of array indices. This improves performance, because every pointer variable access is 1 memory read, and every array variable access is 2 (one for the array variable itself and one for the index variable). The new procedures are over twice as fast as your old ones (Timings are embedded in the source snippets).

The 24 bit buffer needed to be written up, so I rewrote both of your old buffer structures as well. For consistency, more granular sub element access and performance reasons.


The new 16 bit and 32 bit procedures have the same signature as the old ones. That is, they still expect the old buffer types. Note that this is not a problem, because the new types have the same memory footprint as the old ones. The new 24 bit procedure does for obvious reasons use the new 24 bit type.
All the new types and procedures are prefixed with an underscore (_) to differentiate them from your old code.
I didn't have access to PBufferInfoArray, so I gleaned its structure from analyzing your old procedures. This is what I concluded it had to look like:
type
  PBufferInfoArray = ^TBufferInfoArray;
  TBufferInfoArray = array [0..1] of record
    buffers: array [0..0] of Pointer;
  end;


Here is all the new stuff:
Warning: No argument validation or error checking in these functions!
type
  _PBuffer32 = ^_TBuffer32;
  _TBuffer32 = packed record // SizeOf(_TBuffer32) = 4
    case Integer of
      0: (d: Cardinal);
      1: (w0, w1: Word);
      2: (b0, b1, b2, b3: Byte);
  end;

  _PBuffer24 = ^_TBuffer24;
  _TBuffer24 = packed record // SizeOf(_TBuffer24) = 3
    case Integer of
      0: (w0: Word; w1: Byte); // !
      1: (b0, b1, b2: Byte);
  end;

  _PBuffer16 = ^_TBuffer16;
  _TBuffer16 = packed record // SizeOf(_TBuffer16) = 2
    case Integer of
      0: (w: Word);
      1: (b0, b1: Byte);
  end;

// ~92.07 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
function _Deinterleave32(InputBuffer: PBuffer32; OutputBuffer: PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex: LongWord): Boolean;
var
  psrc, esrc: _PBuffer32;
  pdst0, pdst1: _PBuffer32;
begin
  psrc := Pointer(InputBuffer);
  esrc := psrc;
  Inc(esrc, Samples * 2); // The InputBuffer is twice as long as the OutputBuffers.

  pdst0 := OutputBuffer[0].buffers[BufferIndex];
  pdst1 := OutputBuffer[1].buffers[BufferIndex];

  while (NativeInt(psrc) < NativeInt(esrc)) do
  begin
    pdst0.d := psrc.d;
{
    pdst0.b0 := psrc.b0;
    pdst0.b1 := psrc.b1;
    pdst0.b2 := psrc.b2;
    pdst0.b3 := psrc.b3;
}
    Inc(psrc);
    pdst1.d := psrc.d;
{
    pdst1.b0 := psrc.b0;
    pdst1.b1 := psrc.b1;
    pdst1.b2 := psrc.b2;
    pdst1.b3 := psrc.b3;
}
    Inc(psrc);

    Inc(pdst0);
    Inc(pdst1);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

// ~99.70 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
function _Deinterleave24(InputBuffer: _PBuffer24; OutputBuffer: PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex: LongWord): Boolean;
var
  psrc, esrc: _PBuffer24;
  pdst0, pdst1: _PBuffer32;
begin
  psrc := Pointer(InputBuffer);
  esrc := psrc;
  Inc(esrc, Samples * 2); // The InputBuffer is twice as long as the OutputBuffers.

  pdst0 := OutputBuffer[0].buffers[BufferIndex];
  pdst1 := OutputBuffer[1].buffers[BufferIndex];

  while (NativeInt(psrc) < NativeInt(esrc)) do
  begin
    // Data shifted 8 bits to the left to keep the volume.
    pdst0.d := (psrc.w0 or (psrc.w1 shl 16)) shl 8;
{
    pdst0.b0 := 0;
    pdst0.b1 := psrc.b0;
    pdst0.b2 := psrc.b1;
    pdst0.b3 := psrc.b2;
}
    Inc(psrc);
    pdst1.d := (psrc.w0 or (psrc.w1 shl 16)) shl 8;
{
    pdst1.b0 := 0;
    pdst1.b1 := psrc.b0;
    pdst1.b2 := psrc.b1;
    pdst1.b3 := psrc.b2;
}
    Inc(psrc);

    Inc(pdst0);
    Inc(pdst1);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

// ~99.74 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
function _Deinterleave16(InputBuffer: PBuffer16; OutputBuffer: PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex: LongWord): Boolean;
var
  psrc, esrc: _PBuffer16;
  pdst0, pdst1: _PBuffer32;
begin
  psrc := Pointer(InputBuffer);
  esrc := psrc;
  Inc(esrc, Samples * 2); // The InputBuffer is twice as long as the OutputBuffers.

  pdst0 := OutputBuffer[0].buffers[BufferIndex];
  pdst1 := OutputBuffer[1].buffers[BufferIndex];

  while (NativeInt(psrc) < NativeInt(esrc)) do
  begin
    // Data shifted 16 bits to the left to keep the volume.
    pdst0.d := psrc.w shl 16;
{
    pdst0.b0 := 0;
    pdst0.b1 := 0;
    pdst0.b2 := psrc.b0;
    pdst0.b3 := psrc.b1;
}
    Inc(psrc);
    pdst1.d := psrc.w shl 16;
{
    pdst1.b0 := 0;
    pdst1.b1 := 0;
    pdst1.b2 := psrc.b0;
    pdst1.b3 := psrc.b1;
}
    Inc(psrc);

    Inc(pdst0);
    Inc(pdst1);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;


Here are your old untouched procedures (with timings):
// ~232.12 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
procedure Deinterleave32(InputBuffer : PBuffer32; OutputBuffer : PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex : LongWord);
var
  i, j : LongWord;
  Dest : array[0..1] of PBuffer32;
begin
  for i := 0 to 1 do // always 2 channels
    Dest[i] := OutputBuffer[i].buffers[BufferIndex];
  i := 0;
  while i < Samples do
  begin
    j := i shl 1;
    Dest[0][i] := InputBuffer[j];
    Dest[1][i] := InputBuffer[j+1];
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;

// ~264.79 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
procedure Deinterleave16(InputBuffer : PBuffer16; OutputBuffer : PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex : LongWord);
var
  i, j : LongWord;
  Dest : array[0..1] of PBuffer16;
begin
  for i := 0 to 1 do // always 2 channels
    Dest[i] := OutputBuffer[i].buffers[BufferIndex];
  for i := 0 to Samples - 1 do
    for j := 0 to 1 do
      Dest[j][i] := InputBuffer[i*2 + j];
end;


Bonus: Here are your old procedures, but cleaned up a little:
// ~220.23 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
procedure Deinterleave32_clean(InputBuffer: PBuffer32; OutputBuffer: PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex: LongWord);
var
  i   : LongWord;
  Dest: array [0..1] of PBuffer32;
begin
  Dest[0] := OutputBuffer[0].buffers[BufferIndex];
  Dest[1] := OutputBuffer[1].buffers[BufferIndex];

  for i := 0 to (Samples - 1) do
  begin
    Dest[0][i] := InputBuffer[i*2];
    Dest[1][i] := InputBuffer[i*2 + 1];
  end;
end;

// ~143.78 ms (67108864 SAMPLES)
procedure Deinterleave16_clean(InputBuffer: PBuffer16; OutputBuffer: PBufferInfoArray; Samples, BufferIndex: LongWord);
var
  i   : LongWord;
  Dest: array [0..1] of PBuffer16;
begin
  Dest[0] := OutputBuffer[0].buffers[BufferIndex];
  Dest[1] := OutputBuffer[1].buffers[BufferIndex];

  for i := 0 to (Samples - 1) do
  begin
    Dest[0][i] := InputBuffer[i*2];
    Dest[1][i] := InputBuffer[i*2 + 1];
  end;
end;


Additional note: The number of samples used for the timings is arbitrary: (2^24)*4 = 67108864. I used this as sample count for my test buffers.

Wow, thanks so much.  I will need a day to find some time to implement and I'll let you know how it goes and mark your answer at that time.

No problemo! :)

There is a problem in your code, at least with the new Deinterleave32.  My ASIO driver only supports 32-bit. I get static noise as well as the proper audio. Deinterleave32_clean works well though. I hope you can find the problem.

@Ross It's rather hard without knowing the format of the buffers. What I need: 1) Knowledge about which buffer belongs to which channel (i.e. left, right). 2) What is the DC offset point? Is it 0=center or (2^32)/2=center (i.e.: Is the buffer a signed or unsigned 32 bit integer?

@Ross I mean, I could set up some test data buffers...

@Ross I really need the layout of PBufferInfoArray.

@Ross Fixed it. I forgot to account for the fact that the input buffer is twice as long as the two outbut buffers. Necessarily so, since we're deinterleaving them. That fact caused the timings to change, obviously. They are still a bit faster, but not nearly twice as fast.

Your old Deinterleave16 procedure suffers from a different type of problem, btw. That is, it combines pairs of two samples that are two samples away from each other into one sample and writes that alternating into the output buffers. My new version doesn't suffer from that problem.

@Ross However, because 16 bit is a fewer number of bits than 32 bit, it fills the most significant bits with 0's. This effectively causes the output to be in a lower volume than the input. If you want to keep the volume, as it were, you need to also shift the values 16 bits to the left (8 bits for the 24 bit version, but that's a little more involved given the nature of the beast.) Tell me if it works as it is or if I should do any corrections.

@Ross Fixed the shifting, because I assume that's how the audio data is supposed to be formatted. I also left a comment with the equivalent BYTE-wise read/writes in the algorithm so you can see what it's doing. (Reading/writing a full DWORD at a time is faster than performing 4 BYTE reads/writes individually, even when considering the additional mathematical operations, since they are happening on the CPU and not across the bus.)

That fixed it!  At least for 32-bit audio. Cheers!  We will have to try to find a user of my software with ASIO drivers to test at 16 and 24 bit if I can.

Great news! I'm glad to have been of help. Good luck with your software!

fritten, I can't find anyone currently to try 16 or 24-bit output, so I forced my software use the _Deinterleave16 function to see what the noise sounded like and compared it to the old original Deinterleave16.  The results are quite different.  The new _Deinterleave16 sounds 100% the same as _Deinterleave32.  Playback sounds normal and good.  But using the old function adds a lot of static, so I'm presuming the new function isn't doing the same job and isn't correct in some way?  I also forced it to use _Deinterleave24 and it sounds pretty good also just with a slight noise.

I should add that the original audio is actually 16-bit being converted to 32-bits earlier before being deinterleaved, so that may explain the audio sounding ok being deinterleaved at 16-bits?  Although the 2 16-bit functions should perform the same in my mind.

@Ross It's true. They don't perform the exact same operation. I figured that your original 16 bit function might be doing it wrong. But that is based on my reimagining of PBufferInfoArray, since you didn't supply that. In my reimagining, I assume it to always contain 32 bit buffers. It is quite possible that the deinterleave functions require it to be the same bitdepth. But the way the new ones work is they convert the interleaved samples to 32 bit, shift lefted the missing number of bits (8 for 24 bit, 16 for 16 bit) to preserve volume. It should be an easy fix.

@Ross I don't understand why you don't show the layout of PBufferInfoArray. That is the issue I'm struggling with.

I don't think it will help as it is only a pointer.  I would have assumed they are pointing to 16-bit or 24-bit structures in the driver but who knows.  I've updated the original post with the structure.
Someone said they tried 16 and 24-bit output and it sounded perfect, so presumably they do always use 32-bit structures and its all good.

@Ross Oh, but let the person who is actually writing the code decide its relevance. In fact, I'll spare you of asking them: They need overview over the definition of any identifier they are supposed to touch, as a general rule of thumb. Since I now know its definition, I can take more informed decisions. For example, it always holds 2 buffers (likely audio left and right). Also, since they're straight pointers rather than either PBuffer32 or anything else, we can assume it is supposed to hold varying buffer formats (since Pointer is compatible with them all).

@Ross This observation aligns with the functionality of the old 16 bit deinterleave function, and I now know for a fact that both my 16 bit and 24 bit functions are incorrect. That is, they both assume a 32 bit output buffer.

Your last comment seems to contradict your comment above it.  Strange that its working well for one user who has 24 and 16-bit output options in their ASIO driver control panel.  Are you working on a fix then?

I can now confirm the 24 bit output just produces noise. Are you able to help modify your function to make it work?

can you help, or someone else help.  The incoming data must be 24-bit not 32-bit.
